# React - Select Component with similar API as the HTML5 select element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a select component in React which would have a similar api as the html5 select element.

Consider this:

```
<select>
<option value="one"> One </option>
<option value="two" selected> Two </option>
<option value="three"> Three </option>
</select>
```

`selectedOption` would be a state in the top level react `Select` element.

```
...
Class Select extends React.Component {
 state = { selectedOption: //how do i get this value? };
...
```

on click of a child i can call a parent function to activate/select the child

```
<Option onClick={this.props.select}> ...
```

I am just not sure how to infer the initial value of `selectedOption` from the `selected` child prop.

should i set the parent state from child `componentDidMount()` by checking whether child has a `selected` prop and then calling `this.props.select()` ?

OR

should i check the child prop in parent `render` function by mapping over all the `children` and then setting parent state based on it ? (which would be a side effect)

OR is there a better way to handle it? How is it generally done in such scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

**Update Your State**

Update your state so that `selectedOption` is equal to `null`. Your state should look like this:

```
state = {
  selectedOption: null, 
};
```

**Create a `handleChange` Function**

Create a function that will handle the change when the user changes their option and update the state accordingly.

```
handleChange = selectedOption => {
   this.setState({ selectedOption }); //this sets selectedOption to an object containing the value and input of the selection
   //if you want to get the value and the input and store those in separate variables you can do this
   const labelValue = selectedOption.label // this gets whatever label you assigned to labelValue
   const valueOfOption = selectedOption.value //this gets the value of the option and assigns it to valueOfOption  
}
```

Obviously, you can update `state` variables instead of instantiating two new variables (`labelValue` and `valueOfOption`).

**Update Render Function**

Update your render function to call the handle change when there is a change. Update your current source. You have this here:

```
<Option onClick={this.props.select()}>
```

By the way, this `select()` function will be invoked this way regardless of a click. The proper way to do this is: `onClick={() => this.props.select()}`.

You would want this:

```
<Option onClick={this.handleChange}> //should this be onChange? not sure how your Option component is set up though
```

Now, if your `select()` function is a function passed down through props (which it seems like) then you need to handle the selectedOption in your parent component. You didn't share much info on your parent component so I ignored the `select()` function and created the `handleChange()`.

Putting that all together you should have something that looks like this:

```
//necessary imports

class Select extends Component {
   state = {
     selectedOption: null, 
   } 

   handleChange = selectedOption => {
      this.setState({ selectedOption }); 
      const labelValue = selectedOption.label; 
      const valueOfOption = selectedOption.value; 
   } 

   render() {
     const { selectedOption } = this.state; 
     return (
       <div>
         <Option value={selectedOption} onClick={this.handleChange} />
       </div>
     )
   }
} 
export default Select;
```

This should be it.

**Additional Help**

There are a couple react packages that does all of this work for you. I would suggest looking into those so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. The first one that comes to mind is **React Select v2**. You can visit the website [here](https://react-select.com/home) (raw link: https://react-select.com/home). I would suggest going through the examples and the documentation.

The install for **React Select** is: `npm i react-select` or `yarn add react-select`
.

There are others such as `rc-select` or `react-virtualized-select` and more. You can look into them and see which one is best suited for your needs or just continue developing your own.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This doesn't resolve my problem of deriving the initial parent state from child on render. The children may have a 'selected' prop, which decides what is the value of 'selectedOption' , how do we handle that ?
(I understand how to do it onClick )

Comment: so are you passing a function from the parent to the child? and you want to invoke that function in your child component and pass that value back up to your parent? do i understand that correctly

Comment: I want to set parent state based on a child prop, not on the click event, but only on the initial parent render. when the component renders for the first time the parent needs to check if any of the children has a "selected" attribute and set its state based on the value of that attribute. This is only the initial state, from then onwards the state can change based on which child was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting the initial state of parent in `componentDidMount` of parent like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
const { children } = this.props;
let selectedOption = null;
// check if child elements have a 'selected' attribute and set state based on it
React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
  if (child.props.selected) {
    selectedOption = index;
  }
});

this.setState({ selectedOption });
```

}